# Diagonalize two coupling Hamiltonian in second quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, many-body

I want to solve an exercise in Coleman's Introduction to Many Body Physics to understand better exact diagonalization and lattice models:

> Find the transformation that diagonalizes the Hamiltonian
>   \begin{align}
> H=\sum_{j}\left\{J_{1}\left(a_{i+1}^{\dagger} a_{i}+\mathrm{H.c.} )+J_{2}\left(a_{i+1}^{\dagger} a_{i}^{\dagger}+\mathrm{H.c.}\right)\right\}\right.
> \end{align}
>   where the $i$th site is located at $R_j = a j$, and “H.c.” denotes the Hermitian conjugate. You may find it helpful to (i) transform to momentum space, writing
>   $a_{j}=\frac{1}{N^{1 / 2}} \sum_{q} e^{i q R_{j}} a_{q}$, and (ii) carry out a canonical transformation of the form $b_{q}=u_{q} a_{q}+v_{q} a_{-q}^{\dagger}$, where $u^{2} - v^{2} = 1$. What happens when $J_1 = J_2$?

Unfortunately I get lost at the point where it comes to the part finding $u$ and $v$ in order to diagonalize the Hamiltonian. After transforming to momentum space I ended up at: 
\begin{align*}
H=J_{1} \sum_{q} 2 \cos (q a) a_{q}^{\dagger} a_{q}+J_{2} \sum_{q}\left[\mathrm{e}^{-i q a} a_{q}^{\dagger} a_{-q}^{\dagger}+\mathrm{e}^{i q a} a_{-q} a_{q}\right]
\end{align*}
Plugging in the transformation gives 
\begin{align*}
\begin{aligned} H=& J_{1} \sum_{q} 2 \cos (q a)\left[u_{q}^{2} b_{q}^{\dagger} b_{q}+v_{q}^{2} b_{-q} b_{-q}^{\dagger}-u_{q} v_{q}\left(b_{q}^{\dagger} b_{-q}^{\dagger}+b_{-q} b_{q}\right)\right] \\ &+J_{2} \sum_{q} \mathrm{e}^{-i q a}\left[u_{q}^{2} b_{q}^{\dagger} b_{-q}^{\dagger}+v_{q}^{2} b_{-q} b_{q}-u_{q} v_{q}\left(b_{q}^{\dagger} b_{q}+b_{-q} b_{-q}^{\dagger}\right)\right] \\ &+J_{2} \sum_{q} \mathrm{e}^{i q a}\left[u_{q}^{2} b_{-q} b_{q}+v_{q}^{2} b_{q}^{\dagger} b_{-q}^{\dagger}-u_{q} v_{q}\left(b_{-q} b_{-q}^{\dagger}+b_{q}^{\dagger} b_{q}\right)\right] \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
To diagonalize the Hamiltonian one has to cancel out all terms that are not just $a^{\dagger}a$ two equations can be deduced: 
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{l}{-J_{1} 2 \cos (q a) u_{q} v_{q}+J_{2}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-i q a} u_{q}^{2}+\mathrm{e}^{i q a} v_{q}^{2}\right)=0} \\ {-J_{1} 2 \cos (q a) u_{q} v_{q}+J_{2}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-i q a} v_{q}^{2}+\mathrm{e}^{i q a} u_{q}^{2}\right)=0}\end{array}
\end{align*}
**My question**: (1) How to solve this equation? / Another way  (2) What is the physical interpretation of this Hamiltonian, and the $J_1 = J_2$ case?

Comment: Have you tried substituting the hyperbolic sin and cos functions for u and v?

Comment: @noah Yes I tried this with mathematica, but it shows no solution. The main problem are $J_1$ and $J_2$ I think.

Comment: My hunch was that if you substitute the exponential definitions for sinh, cosh, and cos, the expression would simplify somewhat, but I can't go through it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1)

You have to use a trick:

$$\sum_qe^{iqa}a_q^\dagger a_{-q}^\dagger=\frac{1}{2}\sum_q2e^{iqa}a_q^\dagger a_{-q}^\dagger = \frac{1}{2}\sum_q\left(e^{iqa}a_q^\dagger a_{-q}^\dagger+e^{iqa}a_q^\dagger a_{-q}^\dagger\right)$$
Use commutation relations: $[a_{q_1}^\dagger,a_{q_2}^\dagger]=0$ and make the change $q\rightarrow -q$ in sum on second term and you get:
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_qa_q^\dagger a_{-q}^\dagger\left(e^{iqa}+e^{-iqa}\right)=\sum_qa_q^\dagger a_{-q}^\dagger\cos(aq)$$

You do the same thing for hermitian conjugate and you get a nice answer.

(2) The transformation allows you to diagonnalize the Hamiltonian in terms of composite operators by keeping the same basis vectors. I'm not sure about the interpretation of this but I would say that it would mean that there exist a "composite" particle of your original particles involved in the hamiltonian that corresponds to the eigenstates of the original hamiltonian. A bit like excitons or polarons are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian with electromagnetic coupling with a crystal.

The case $J_1=J_2$ gives an eigenvalue of $0$ in the new operators form for any eigenvector. Again, I'm not too sure about the interpretation but I would say that the linear transform would not work anymore in this case. And, actually, you could rewrite your original hamiltonian in another form that would be diagonal in another basis (e.g.: $(\sim (a_q^\dagger+a_q)^2$)).

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what I'm looking for :) From this we can follow one equation which need to be fulfilled to get rid of the non-diagonal terms: 
 \begin{align*}
  - J_1 2 \cos (qa) u_q v_q + J_2 \cos(qa) (  u_q^{2} +  v_q^{2} ) &= 0 \\
 \Rightarrow - J_1 u_q v_q + J_2 (  u_q^{2} +  v_q^{2} ) &= 0
 \end{align*}
Together with $u^{2} - v^{2} = 1$ we get 
\begin{align*}
u_{q} &=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\frac{J_{1}^{2}}{J_{1}^{2}-J_{2}^{2}}\right)^{1 / 2}+1\right]} \\ v_{q} &=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\frac{J_{1}^{2}}{J_{1}^{2}-J_{2}^{2}}\right)^{1 / 2}-1\right]} 
\end{align*} It seems that...

Comment: there is indeed no canonical transformation which can diagonalize the Hamiltonian for $J_1 = J_2$.